# MySQL fetching rows from 2 tables (not relational) with LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have the following 2 tables

**table_article**:

```
id  subject     tags
---------------------
1   subject-1   2,4,5
2   subject-2   3,5
3   subject-3   1,2
4   subject-4   2,3,4
5   subject-5   3
```

**table_tags**:

```
id  tag_name
---------------------
1   php
2   jQuery
3   css
4   mysql
5   java
```

and I'm trying to get results like

```
id => 1, subject => subject-1, tag_names => jQuery,mysql,java
id => 2, subject => subject-2, tag_names => css,java
id => 3, subject => subject-3, tag_names => php,jQuery
```

Here is my current attempt, which returns ONLY the first tag (e.g. 2 instead of 2,4,5 for row 1)

```
 1    SELECT
 2        table_article.id,
 3        table_article.subject,
 4        GROUP_CONCAT(table_tags.tag_name) AS tag_names
 5    FROM
 6        table_article
 7    LEFT JOIN
 8        table_tags
 9    ON
10        (table_tags.tag_id IN (table_article.tags))
11    GROUP BY
12        table_article.id
13    LIMIT
14        3
```

and the results are

```
id => 1, subject => subject-1, tag_names => jquery
id => 2, subject => subject-2, tag_names => css
id => 3, subject => subject-3, tag_names => php
```

The problem occurs on **line 10** -> `IN (table_article.tags)`.

I just can't figure out how could I solve this problem, can anyone help please?

Comment: When you say "not relational", do you mean "not normalized"? Because it looks like your tables *are* relational, in that they have a primary key. No?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I would use `IN` in this situation, it won't work, replace it with `FIND_IN_SET(table_tags.tag_id, table_article.tags) > 0` and you'll be fine.  Though you really should normalize this.

Comment: Just FYI, Bill was right that you need to `>0` at the end, if it's 0, that mean's its not in the set. +1 to @BillKarwin

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a string that happens to contain commas as a list of discrete values.

In other words this:

```
ON table_tags.tag_id IN (2,4,5)
```

Is not the same as this:

```
ON table_tags.tag_id IN ('2,4,5')
```

The numeric value of a string like '2,4,5' is the initial numeric portion, and the remainder after the first non-numeric character is ignored.  So the string '2,4,5' has a numeric value of 2.  It won't be an error, but it won't get you what you intended, which is a match against any of the values in the comma-separated list.

MySQL has a built-in function [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) which does understand strings that contain comma-separated values.  The function returns the position of the matching value, or 0 if no match was found.

```
ON FIND_IN_SET(table_tags.tag_id, '2,4,5') > 0
```

But this cannot use an index and it forces you to run a table-scan which is going to kill your performance.  To be clear, I don't recommend using this function in a join condition.

The answer is: **Don't store tags in a comma-separated list.**  See my answer for [Is storing a comma separated list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-comma-separated-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)

Store one tag per row in a separate table, as @Martin Lyne suggests.  That way you can look for the right tag with `=` and you can even index the column for much better performance.

Comment: Looks like you had the same suggestion.

Comment: I don't recommend using FIND_IN_SET() in a join condition.

Comment: It seems that I'm going the wrong way. Yes, I DID have another table for linking table_article and table_tags, with each entry on its own row. I'd better keep it there now. Thanks for the info Bill. As for my specific question, I'll take bigman's answer as accepted.

Comment: @BillKarwin You are right about the `> 0`, updated my answer. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

I've not seen an IN in a ON before (not saying it's not valid) but  I would do `ON table_tags.tag_id = table_article.tags)`

So you end up with multiple rows

```
subject-1, query
subject-1, css
subject 2, query
```

then the `GROUP BY` would compress the table and the `GROUP_CONCAT` gets all the missing tags.

Answer (score 0):

As other said, this is not a good design.

Instead, you could change your table design this way:

```
table_article
   id
   subject

article_tag
   article_id
   tag_id

table_tags
   id
   tag_name
```

Life would be much easier this way :-)

Comment: As I said to Bill, I had exactly the same design as you suggested. I was just being stupid whishing to remove a table :)